# Measure Theory Exercise, subsets of (0,1) such that there are $x,y: x+y =1$ (verification)

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Show that for Lebesgue measurable sets $A,B \subset (0,1) $ such that $\mu(A) > \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mu(B) > \frac{1}{2}$, there
> exists $x \in A$  and $y \in B$  such that $x+y = 1$

Solution:
Let $C = \{z \in (0,1): z = 1-y, y \in B\}$. If $A \cap C \neq \emptyset$, then we are done. If not, then $A$ and $C$ are disjoint. Now $\mu(B) = \mu(C)$, ie $\mu(C) >\frac{1}{2}$ so by additivity

$$\mu(A) + \mu(C) > 1$$
which can't be, since they are both disjoint subsets of $(0,1)$. Hence their intersection is not empty, and we have the result.

---

I am essentially concerned about the conclusion that $\mu(C) = \mu(B)$, since everything else is rather straightforward. It seems like there is no way that this cannot be true, but measure theory is of course occasionally very counter intuitive.

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826821/real-analysis-folland-theorem-1-21-borel-measures

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works... Using the definition of Lebesgue measure here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure

$$\mu(B)=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(I_k) \mid \{I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \text{ is a sequence of closed intervals with }  C\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k  \right\}$$

$y\in B$ means that $y$ is in some of the closed intervals $I_k$ so that $z=1-y$ is in some of the closed intervals $J_k=1-I_k$ defined by $1-[a,b]=[1-b,1-a]$ and we have that $\mu(J_k)=\mu(I_k)$.

So that 
$$\begin{aligned}
\mu(C)&=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(J_k) \mid \{J_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \text{ is a sequence of closed intervals with }  C\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k  \right\}\\
&=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(1-I_k) \mid \{1-I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \text{ is a sequence of closed intervals with }  C\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (1-I_k)  \right\}\\
&=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(1-I_k) \mid \{I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \text{ is a sequence of closed intervals with }  B\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (I_k)  \right\}\\
&=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(I_k) \mid \{I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \text{ is a sequence of closed intervals with }  B\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k  \right\}\\
&=\mu(B)
\end{aligned}$$

Thus we can conclude that $\mu(C)=\mu(B)$.

This might be a little sloppy and should be refined though.