# translation and dilation invariance of borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I am studying the book "Real Analysis" by Folland, and I have a question about the following. Folland writes on pg 37 that:

> Since the collection of open intervals is invariant under translations and dilations, the same is true of Borel sets in $R$

I understand the "since $\dots$ dilations" part, but why does this mean that the same is true of Borel sets? It seems true, but what is the proof of this claim?

Answer (score 7):

Proofs of things about $\sigma$-algebras often begin by saying "Let $A=$..." and proceed by showing that $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Here: Let $A$ be the collection of all sets $E$ such that every translate of $E$ is a Borel set and every dilate of $E$ is a Borel  set. Show that $A$ is a $\sigma$_algebra. Since open intervals are in $A$ and the Borel sets are the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open intervals it follows that every Borel  set is in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a tranlsation $\phi(x) = x+a$.  Then $\phi$ is a bijection, so it preserves countable unions, countable intersections, and complements:
$$
\phi\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \phi(A_n)
\\
\phi\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \phi(A_n)
\\
\mathbb R \setminus \phi(A) = \phi\left(\mathbb R \setminus A\right)
$$

Can you prove this?  Do you see how to prove your result using this?

Comment: I can prove that bijection preserves countable union/intersection and complements, but how do I use this to prove my result?

Answer (score 1):

As David's answer describes, the primary technique to show that some property is true for all Borel sets is to show that the collection of all sets satisfying the property is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains the open sets.

With this technique in mind, we can prove the following generalization.

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism. A subset $B$ of $X$ is Borel iff $f(B)$ is Borel.

To prove this, use the technique described above with the one hinted by GEdgar. That is, first use the fact that $f$ is a bijection to show that the collection of all subsets $A$ of $X$ such that $f(A)$ is Borel is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then show that this $\sigma$-algebra contains the open sets (and thus the Borel sets) by using the property that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Borel measurable function gives us the preimage of the Borel set is Borel. Thus we should use subtraction instead of addition.

Take $B⊂R$, and $t∈\mathbb{R}$, then take $f(b) = b - t$ for all $b∈B$. This is continuous, thus Borel measurable. Therefore, $f-1(B)$ is Borel measurable. However, $f-1(B)$ is exactly $t+B$, therefore, $t+B$ is Borel measurable.

For dilation, we would use dividing instead, but just be careful when $t$ is $0$ but $0*B$ is just a single point that is open.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to answer the question (or, rather, it addresses the question which was actually asked rather tangentially).  The original questions asks for a justification of the statement "The collection of open intervals is invariant under translations and dilations, therefore the collection of Borel sets is also invariant under translations and dilations."  The distinction between addition and subtraction here is irrelevant---both are translations.  I think that the other preexisting answers address this point better...